# Display Java console output in R using rJava

Tags: java, r, knitr, stdout, rjava

I have created the following Java class and saved it as `Test.java`, then compiled into `Test.class` on the command line using `javac Test.java`:

```java
public class Test {

  public Test() {
  }

  public double power(double number) {
    System.out.println("calculating...");
    return number * number;
  }
}
```

Furthermore, I have created the following R script and saved it as `test.R`:

```r
library("rJava")
.jinit(classpath = getwd())
test <- .jnew("Test")
.jcall(test, "D", "power", 3)
```

When I execute it, for example using `R CMD BATCH test.R` on the command line, I get the following output, which is what I want:

```
calculating...
[1] 9
```

However, when I wrap this script in a Markdown document and compile it using knitr, I lose the message that is printed about the calculation taking place. For example, I save the following script in `test.Rmd` and compile it using RStudio:

````r
```{r echo=TRUE, warning=TRUE, results='show', message=TRUE}
library("rJava")
.jinit(classpath = getwd())
test <- .jnew("Test")
.jcall(test, "D", "power", 3)
```
````

This only returns the following output, without the message:

```
## [1] 9
```

I read somewhere that the reason is that `System.out.println` in Java writes to `stdout`, and whether this is shown in the R console or not depends on the interpreter. For example, the output is shown on Unix systems but not on Windows or in knitr.

My questions:

1. Is the above interpretation correct?
2. How can I reliably capture or display the output of `System.out.println` in R, irrespective of operating system or interpreter?
3. If that's not possible, what is a better way of designing status messages about the current calculations and progress in Java, such that R can display these messages?
   Thanks!

Comment: Frustratingly, I found (at some point) that java output bypasses much of R's way of doing things. Not much of an answer, more of an omen that *"this should be easy but I found it not"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take a stab at answering my own question... Looks like the RJava folks actually offer a built-in solution (thanks Simon Urbanek if you read this). On the side of the Java code, there is the LGPL-licensed `JRI.jar`, which is delivered with rJava (look at the `jri` sub-directory in the `rJava` package directory in your local R library path) and which can be copied/extracted into the Java library path. It's only 82kb, so fairly light-weight.

JRI offers a replacement of the default print stream in Java. Essentially, you redirect the system output into an `RConsoleOutputStream` provided by JRI. The code in my question above can be modified as follows to print to the R console instead of stdout.

```java
import java.io.PrintStream;
import org.rosuda.JRI.RConsoleOutputStream;
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;

public class Test {

  public Test() {
    Rengine r = new Rengine();
    RConsoleOutputStream rs = new RConsoleOutputStream(r, 0);
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(rs));
  }

  public double power(double number) {
    System.out.println("calculating...");
    return number * number;
  }
}
```